# Preemphasis circuit, calculating H(s) and Bode plot

Tags: transfer-function, bode-plot

I have the following circuit: (which should represent a "new" design for preemphasis block in a FM transmitter circuit)
[image]

I need to calculate the transfer function H(s) and draw a Bode plot.
My question is, how to do it fast and efficient with respect to time since I won't have a computer
to use in my exam.

Here's an example from NI Multisim bode plot:

[image]

I need help to calculate the H(s) and bode plot manually.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you calculate that at DC the gain is -42.35 dB (a good place to start)?

Comment: Maybe, The question is how to do the equations to calculate the transfer function. I am expected to have: Two Node equations + solving TWO equations with numbers and s as a parameter

Comment: Maybe isn't sure enough. If you don't see the importance of this first calculation then what help can I give that is meaningful?

Comment: What do you mean with "*how to do it fast and efficient with respect to **time***"? I thought you need H(s)? Otherwise you seem to have a shelf highpass and a (loaded) lowpass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be fast and be efficient to determine transfer functions, there is no other way than resorting to the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs that I describe in my [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371) on the subject. However, and it could be the issue for an exam, I am not sure if the person who reviews your contribution will recognize it as a valid method as he/she perhaps expects the classical KVL/KCL approach.

The methods relies on determining the time constants when the stimulus - \$V_{in}\$ - is reduced to 0 V or replaced by a short circuit. You first start with \$s=0\$ and opens the caps (and short the inductors if any), just like what SPICE does during its bias point analysis. You determine the dc gain \$H_0\$ in this mode. Then, you temporarily remove each capacitor and "look" through its connecting terminals to determine by inspection (no equations) the resistance \$R\$ you see. Then, multiply the resistance by the involved capacitor to form the time constant \$\tau=RC\$. So determining the transfer function is mostly about splitting the circuit into small drawings that you individually solve and eventually fix if you spot a mistake in the end.

[image]

Once you have the *natural* time constants, you can form the denominator. For the zero, you have to identify a specific impedance in the circuit which could block the stimulus propagation if tuned at the zero frequency. As highlighted in the below picture, it is when the parallel combination of \$C_1\$ and \$R_1\$ would become infinite. And this is true for \$s=s_z=-\frac{1}{R_1C_1}\$.

[image]

This is it, we have everything to be happy and a Mathcad sheet can check these results. I usually build a *high-entropy* expression obtained with Thévenin in this case and make sure both answers are rigorously similar in magnitude and phase. This is the case here. As I said, should you spot a small deviation, then review the individual sketches and fix the guilty one without restarting from scratch as any other analysis would require:

[image]

Because the roots are real in this circuit (the quality factor is low), you can try to model the transfer function with two cascaded poles and a zero. As shown in the below plots, all three expressions deliver the exact same response:

[image]

If I count the time needed to determine the expression using FACTs, it does not exceed a few minutes. Should I now expand the Thévenin expression, first it's likely that I make mistakes while expanding the equations but, second, I will need more time to format the expression in a nice *low-entropy* format.

[image]

Comment: This answer is more than fine.

Comment: Thank you, I hope it will motivate you to discover and master the FACTs! Have a look at my [APEC 2016](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf) seminar for a smooth introduction on the subject.